# SWT Click on a single cell in a Table

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a Table from SWT, each line of the Table is a TableItem.
I need to be able to click on a single cell of the Table but currently I could only select the entire row, I can edit each cell however but I don't want to see the selection on the entire row.

```
private Table table;
table.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {

  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    Point pt = new Point(event.x, event.y);
    TableItem item = table.getItem(pt);
    if (item != null) {
      for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        Rectangle rect = item.getBounds(col);
        if (rect.contains(pt)) {
          item.setText(col, "test");
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828053/how-to-select-one-cell-from-swt-table/41491965 helps?

Comment: It doesn't help, still it selects the whole line in that post.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Generate a click event? Draw the selection for only the cell?

Comment: Draw the selection for only the cell. I am able to edit each cell but I want to draw the selection for only one cell.

Comment: There is no simple way to do that. You would have to use the 'owner draw' method of drawing the table yourself using the `SWT.EraseItem`, `SWT.MeasureItem` and `SWT.PaintItem` events (in JFace you can use `OwnerDrawLabelProvider`).

Comment: You could use NatTable instead. NatTable allows cell selection.